# How to save input data after refresh in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, input, save, phonegap

I'm using Phonegap to create an app that lets the user write down what exercises they've been doing at the gym. The problem is that when the user adds another set or exercise the data in the previous input gets deleted...

```js
function addTableRow(id, set) {
  document.getElementById('table-' + id).innerHTML += '<tr style="color:white"><td class="set">' + set + '</td><td><input class="input" style="left:25%" value="x"></input></td><td><input class="input" style="left:60%" value="kg x reps"></input></td></tr>';
  document.getElementById('table-plus-set-' + id).onclick = function() {
    addTableRow(id, set + 1);
  };
}

function addTableExersice(id, exersice) {
  document.getElementById('exersice-holder').innerHTML += '<div class="exersice"><table style="width:100%" id="table-' + exersice + '">Exercise: <input placeholder="Input exersice" class="enter-Exercise"></input><tr style="color:white"><th>SET</th><th>GOAL</th> <th>ACHIEVED</th></tr><tr style="color:white"><td class="set">1</td><td><input class="input" style="left:25%" value="x"></input></td><td><input class="input" style="left:60%" value="kg x reps"></input></td></tr></table><div class="plusSet" onclick="addTableRow(' + exersice + ', 2)" id="table-plus-set-' + exersice + '">+</div></div>';
  document.getElementById('table-plus-exersice-1').onclick = function() {
    addTableExersice(id, exersice + 1);
  };
}
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.set {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.exersice {
  width: 100%;
  ;
  height: auto;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0%;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.exersice table {
  color: white;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.plusSet {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plusExersice {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.enter-Exercise {
  width: 70%;
}

.exersice-holderStyle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="exersice-holder" class="exersice-holderStyle">
  <div class="exersice">
    <table style="width:100%" id="table-1">
      Exercise: <input placeholder="Input exersice" class="enter-Exercise"></input>
      <tr style="color:white">
        <th>SET</th>
        <th>GOAL</th>
        <th>ACHIEVED</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:white">
        <td class="set">1</td>
        <td><input class="input" value="x"></input>
        </td>
        <td><input class="input" value="kg x reps"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="plusSet" onclick="addTableRow(1, 2)" id="table-plus-set-1">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="plusExersice" onclick="addTableExersice(1, 2)" id="table-plus-exersice-1">+</div>
</div>
```

Can I in some way, write something in the <'script'> to make the input data stay after an onclick tableExercise/tableRow?

I appreciate any help with this :) 
PS. I'm pretty new to this so im sorry if the code is a bit messy...

Answer (score 0):

This could maybe help you save values in Phonegap javascript scripts:  **Local Storage**

**Set value**

```
localStorage.setItem("mytime", Date.now());
```

**Read value**

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("mytime");
```

**Doc**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_storage.asp